# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver>

Tags: android

Since I migrated from Android 30 to Android 31, I get the following error:

> Error:    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element
> <receiver#com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver>.
> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an
> explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component
> has an intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.

However, I have no element `AppMeasurementReceiver` in my code anywhere. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was the following dependency in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Fortunately I don't need this anymore, so by removing it, everything worked again.